# How can I send a chain of characters to a cmd.exe from c++?

Tags: c++, cmd

I tried with findwindow and sendmessage, but, with sendmessage I only can send message for the  GUI. Help!!!!!

Comment: If you're just wanting to make the window think you're typing, `SendMessage` with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` would be the way to go. Let cmd do the translating. Emulating input seems a bit extreme for just one specific window. Not 100% sure if I get exactly what you hope to accomplish though.

Comment: For the best answer you should give more information. Can you launch the console app yourself? Why are you doing this at all? Which app are you trying to automate?

Comment: Chances are that if we know what your eventual goal is, we can point you to a better method than messing around with the window.

Comment: Hi, I want to write in cmd with an other program in c++, for controlling another program which I cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It's not very friendly so if you want to use it for complex tasks you may take a look to [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6819/SendKeys-in-C) on CodeProject that emulates the well-known [SendKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command for VBScript/.NET.

Comment: "Note: This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead." Right in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best way to start command line process using CreateProcess function that takes STARTUPINFO structure with input / output handles specified.

When cmd process is already started use SendInput. But IMHO this way is less reliable.